# Laravel 9: How to sort by client title on an invoice index page

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a datatable which shows a paginated list of invoices. Each row has the invoice number, the client it belongs to and some other details about the invoice. My issue is if i try to sort the table by client it breaks the query and throws a mysql error.

I realise this is due to the fact that the clients title is not in the invoice, it is using the clients id. How can i do this? I'm using datatables.net method. In my layout i have the following in the head linking to this library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.12.1/b-2.2.3/b-colvis-2.2.3/b-html5-2.2.3/cr-1.5.6/r-2.3.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

This works by the blade template showing only the header and using ajax to call a function which returns the required data contents. The datatables.net js file creates the filters and a search bar.

```
<table id="invoices" class="eclipse table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <td style="width:34px;">ID</td>
                <td style="width:120px">Invoice #</td>
                <td style="width:128px">Ref Number</td>
                <td style="width:128px">Client</td>
                <td style="width:80px">Date</td>
                <td style="width:70px">Hours</td>
                <td style="width:100px">Amount</td>
                <td style="width:124px">Itemised Work Items</td>
                <td>Comment</td>
                <td style="width:32px;">Can Edit?</td>
                <td style="width:96px">Status</td>
                <td style="width:16px;">...</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
        var menu   = document.getElementById("menu-holder");
        var span   = document.getElementById("close-menu");
        var modal  = document.getElementById("myModal");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#invoices').DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "order": [0, 'desc'],
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    url: "/invoices/data/",
                    method: "get"
                },
                "columnDefs" : [
                    {
                        "targets": [-1],
                        "data": null,
                        "visible": true,
                        "defaultContent": '<button>{!! config( 'ecl.BURGER' ) !!}</button>'
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [0],
                        "visible": false
                    }
                ],
            });
            $("#invoices tbody").on("click", "button", function () {
                $("#menu-holder").html( '' );
                var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                $("#content-region").html( '' );
                // Show popup form
                var url = $( this ).data("url");
                // now call ajax on this url
                call_ajax( "/invoice/" + data[0] + "/action" );
                modal.style.backgroundColor = null;
                modal.style.display = "none";
                menu.style.display = "block";
            });
            $("#add-new-invoice").on("click", function () {
                // Show popup form
                var url = $( this ).data("url");
                // now call ajax on this url
                call_ajax( url );
                modal.style.display = "block";
                loader.style.display = "block";
            })
            span.onclick = function() {
                loader.style.display = "none";
                modal.style.display = "none";
                menu.style.display = "none";
                modal.style.backgroundColor = '#fefefe';
            }
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target === menu) {
                    loader.style.display = "none";
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                    menu.style.display = "none";
                    modal.style.backgroundColor = '#fefefe';
                }
            }
        });

        function call_ajax( url ) {
            // ToDo make an actual ajax call to get the form data
            $.get( url )
                .done(
                    function( data ) {
                        $("#menu-holder").html( data );
                    }
                )
                .fail(
                    function() {
                        $("#menu-holder").html( "<p>error</p>" );
                    }
                );
        }
    </script>
```

The ajax is called via a url of `/invoices/data/` this calls this function in a controller:

```
public function dataSource(Request $request): array
    {
        return Invoice::dataSource( $request );
    }
```

and this is the dataSource function in the Invoice model:

```
    public static function dataSource( Request $request )
    {
        $sortColumns = array(
            0 => 'id',
            1 => 'number',
            2 => 'ref_number',
            3 => 'clients.title',
            4 => 'date',
            5 => 'amount',
            6 => 'itemised',
            7 => 'comment',
            8 => 'editable',
            9 => 'status',
            10 => 'actions'
        );

        $query = self::select( 'invoices.*' );

        $searchFields = ['comment', 'clients.title', 'number'];
        $with         = [];

        [$query, $json] = getDataSourceQuery( $query, $request, $with, $sortColumns, $searchFields );

        $invoices = $query->get(); // <- This is where the error happens

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            // Get active jobs for this client.
            if ( $invoice->type === 'INV' ) {
                $job = Job::find( $invoice->number );
                $client = $job->client->title;
                $refNumber = '<a href="/job/' . $invoice->number . '/show"><span class="font-extrabold text-pink-800 dark:text-pink-300">Job #' . sprintf('%07d', $invoice->number) . '</span></a>';
            } elseif ( $invoice->type === 'CLI' ) {
                $client = Client::find( $invoice->number )->title;
                $refNumber = '<a href="/client/' . $invoice->number . '/manage"><span class="font-extrabold text-green-800 dark:text-green-300">Client #' . sprintf('%07d', $invoice->number ) . '</span></a>';
            } else {
                $project = Project::find( $invoice->number );
                $client = $project->client->title;
                $refNumber = '<a href="/project/' . $invoice->number . '/manage"><span class="font-extrabold text-purple-800 dark:text-purple-300">Project #' . sprintf('%07d', $invoice->number ) . '</span></a>';
            }

            $lWeight = '700';
            $dWeight = '300';
            $bg = 'transparent';

            switch ( $invoice->status) {
                default:
                case 'DRAFT':
                    $colour = 'blue';
                    $link = false;
                    break;
                case 'LEGACY':
                    $colour = 'gray';
                    $link = false;
                    break;
                case 'DELETED':
                case 'VOIDED':
                    $colour = 'red';
                    $link = true;
                    break;
                case 'SUBMITTED':
                    $colour = 'orange';
                    $lWeight = '500';
                    $dWeight = '400';
                    $link = true;
                    break;
                case 'AUTHORISED':
                    $colour = 'green';
                    $link = true;
                    break;
                case 'PAID':
                    $colour = 'stone';
                    $bg = 'emerald-300';
                    $link = true;
                    break;
            }

            $status = '
                <div class="text-center w-full h-full bg-' . $bg . '">';
            if ( $link && !is_null( $invoice->xero_id ) ) {
                $status .= '
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://go.xero.com/AccountsReceivable/Edit.aspx?InvoiceID=' . $invoice->xero_id . '">';
                if (!is_null($invoice->xero_id)) {
                    $status .= '
                        <div class="is-xero"></div>';
                }
            }

            $status .= '
                        <span class="font-extrabold bg-' . $bg . ' text-' . $colour . '-' . $lWeight . ' dark:text-' . $colour . '-' . $dWeight . '">' . $invoice->status . '</span>';

            if ( $link && !is_null( $invoice->xero_id ) ) {
                $status .= '
                    </a>';
            }

            $status .= '
                </div>';

            $countWork     = JobWorkItem::where( 'invoice_id', $invoice->id )->count();
            $countPurchase = JobPurchaseItem::where( 'invoice_id', $invoice->id )->count();

             $json['data'][] = [
                 $invoice->id,
                 '<div class="w-full h-full bg-' . $bg . '">
                    <a href="/invoice/' . $invoice->id . '">
                        <span class="font-extrabold text-' . $colour . '-' . $lWeight . ' dark:text-' . $colour . '-' . $dWeight . '">
                            #' . $invoice->type . sprintf( '%07d', $invoice->id ) . '
                        </span>
                    </a>
                 </div>',
                 $refNumber,
                 $client,
                 date_format( $invoice->created_at, 'Y-m-d' ),
                 time_format( $invoice->hours + 0.0 ),
                 '£' . number_format( $invoice->amount, 2 ),
                 ( $invoice->is_itemised ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . ' - ' . $countWork . 'w | ' . $countPurchase . 'p',
                 $invoice->comment,
                 $invoice->allowEdit() ? 'yes' : 'no',
                 $status,
            ];
        }

        return $json;

    }
```

and the helper function which handles the query `getDataSourceQuery`:

```
/**
 * @param Builder|HasManyThrough $query
 * @param Request $request
 * @param array $with
 * @param array $sortColumns
 * @param array $searchFields
 * @return array
 */
function getDataSourceQuery(Builder|HasManyThrough $query,
                            Request $request,
                            array   $with,
                            array   $sortColumns,
                            array   $searchFields
) :array
{
    $count = $query->count();
    $search = $request->query('search', array('value' => '', 'regex' => false));
    $draw = $request->query('draw', 0);
    $start = $request->query('start', 0);
    $length = $request->query('length', 25);
    $order = $request->query('order', [['column' => 0, 'dir' => 'asc']]);

    $column = $sortColumns[$order[0]['column']];
    $dir    = $order[0]['dir'];

    $filter = $search['value'];

    if ( str_contains( $column, '.' ) ) {
        $boom = explode('.', $column );
        $table = $query->getModel()->getTable();
        $query->join( $boom[0], $table . '.number', '=', $column );
    }

    if (!empty($filter)) {
        foreach ( $searchFields as $index => $field ) {
            if ( $index === 0 ) {
                $query->where($field, 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
            } else {
                $query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
            }
        }
    }

    $query->orderBy($column, $dir)
        ->with( $with )
        ->take($length)
        ->skip($start);



//    $qry = $query->toSql();
//    $bindings = $query->getBindings();

    $json = array(
        'draw' => $draw,
        'recordsTotal' => $count,
        'recordsFiltered' => $count,
        'data' => [],
    );

    return [$query, $json];
}
```

This works on page loading but when i click the Client column (title) it is failing due to the invoice model not having a client title. Filtering by client_id will not sort the clients by alphabetical order as they are not entered in any specific order. The client model has only an id, a title and a contact email column.

So reiterating the question how can I define my query to search for the client's title and sort them alphabetically?

I should point out that overall and elsewhere within the app this is working but there are other columns on other tables which also reference elements in another model or in some instances a function to render the result and also break.

Any solution to referencing an element in another model or a function would be appreciated.

thanks

*** EDIT *** I've added in a join in the helper function (code above updated) I now get an empty result when i sort by clients title. The query created is `` select `invoices`.* from `invoices` inner join `clients` on `invoices`.`number` = `clients`.`title` order by `clients`.`title` asc limit 10 offset 0; ``

Comment: Added missing code for helper function getDataSourceQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the join, I was comparing the client_id to the title and not the id for the client. All working now.